# Spatial join and sum aggregation of two polygon GeoDataFrames in GeoPandas

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, spatial-join, aggregation

I would like to join two GeoDataFrames with polygon geometries (purple and green, see screenshot below). However, I would like to get the sum of all intersecting green areas per purple feature they are intersecting with.

[image]

I tried

```py
import geopandas as gpd

gpd.sjoin(purple, green, how="inner", op='intersects')
```

but that will just tell me which features are intersecting rather than returning the sum of the intersecting green areas. How would I do this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Intersect](https://geopandas.org/set_operations.html) and [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) results back to the green polygons:

```
import geopandas as gpd

dfpurple = gpd.read_file(r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\geopandas_sjoin_interaera\buffer.shp")

dfgreen = gpd.read_file(r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\geopandas_sjoin_interaera\counties.shp")
id_col = 'kkod' #Unique identifier to tell the green areas apart

dfpurp_diss = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gpd.GeoSeries([geom for geom in dfpurple.unary_union.geoms])) #Dissolve the purple overlaps
dfpurp_diss.geometry = dfpurp_diss[0] #Set a geometry column
dfpurp_diss.crs = dfgreen.crs #My crs was undefined

intersect = gpd.overlay(dfgreen, dfpurp_diss, how='intersection') #Intersect
intersect['area'] = intersect.geometry.area #Calculate area column

interarea = intersect.groupby(id_col)['area'].sum() #Sum per id_col

dfgreen = dfgreen.merge(right=interarea, how='left', left_on=id_col, right_index=True) #Merge/Join the data back to the original data
```

[image]